# Discord bot not giving the username of the target

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've been trying to make a command for my discord bot in which my bot should write the name of the target (the person I'm mentioning) in an embed, but unfortunately, nothing has been working.

```js
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content === "R!kill") {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        const yoyoyo = msg.author.username;
        const target = msg.mentions.members.first();
        embed.setTitle(`**OKAY, LES KILL ${target}**`);
        embed.setImage("https://i.redd.it/ijh28d8tw0d11.jpg"), embed.setColor("RANDOM"), embed.setFooter(`mission complete`), msg.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

I have even tried changing `const target = msg.mentions.members.first();` to `const target = msg.mentions.members.first.username();` but it's still not working.

---

[image]

Comment: Use msg.startsWith(...) instead of msg.content ==

Comment: You mean `msg.content.startsWith()`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mention someone in the message along with the command, the content of the message ([`Message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)) won't be equal to only `R!kill`.

It will be something like `R!kill <@!524243315319898133>`. With the number being the id of the user you mentioned.

You more likely want to check if the content [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) the command. (As Tyler2P said in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68590458/discord-bot-not-giving-the-username-of-the-target/68591214#comment121218453_68590458).)

And to get a username of the user, you can use [`GuildMember.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user), which has property [`username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username). In your case, `target` is an instance of `GuildMember`.

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith("R!kill")) {

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    const target = msg.mentions.members.first();

    // Add check if no one is mentioned, we return from the function
    if (!target) {
        msg.channel.send("Who should I kill?");
        return;
    }

    embed.setTitle(`**OKAY, LES KILL ${target.user.username}**`);
    embed.setImage("https://i.redd.it/ijh28d8tw0d11.jpg"), embed.setColor("RANDOM"), embed.setFooter(`mission complete`), msg.channel.send(embed);

}
```

[image]

Comment: hey im getting an error on this, my console keeps saying 'illegal return statement' , and when i remove the return statement, it starts giving me more error that 'msg is not defined' etc.

Comment: Did you put the code inside of your `bot.on("message", (msg) => ...)` event callback?

Answer (score 0):

`msg.mentions.members.first();` returns a `<GuildMember>` object, from which you can access its `#displayName` property to get its respective guild member name. So transform that into: `msg.mentions.members.first().displayName`.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that you put only `target`, when you should obtain first the user, and then the username, as the following: `target.user.username`

```js
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content === "R!kill") {
    
    if (!target) return; // If no mention return.

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        const yoyoyo = msg.author.username;
        const target = msg.mentions.members.first();
        embed.setTitle(`**OKAY, LES KILL ${target.user.username}**`);
        embed.setImage("https://i.redd.it/ijh28d8tw0d11.jpg"), embed.setColor("RANDOM"), embed.setFooter(`mission complete`), msg.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not the main problem. If `msg.content === "R!kill"` how would there be a `target`? If `msg.content === "R!kill"` there is no one mentioned.